# Are my formulas for the shell and washer methods correct in relation to the problem?

Tags: calculus, volume

I have been working on this problem for a while, which gives me a region R bounded by the curves of $ \ \ x = y^2 + 2$, $ \  \ y = x - 4$, and $ \ \ y = 0$.
I am to find the volume of R when it is rotated about the x-axis.

I tried both the washer and shell method for this one problem in order to solidify my understanding of this topic but instead, I raised more questions for myself because both methods produced different answers.

Washer : $$\int_2^6\pi((\sqrt{x-2})^2-(x-4)^2)\, dx = \frac{8\pi}{3}$$

Shell : $$\int_0^22\pi y((y+4)-(y^2+2))\, dy = \frac{16\pi}{3}$$

I am hopeful that my formula and answer for the washer method portion is correct. I am also aware that for the shell method portion, I would have gotten
$$\frac{8\pi}{3}$$ if I did not multiply it by $2$. However, the shell method calls for this formula structure, which includes the 2—so what gives? I am confused and I hope someone can shed some light on this for me. Thanks!

Comment: Split into two regions if you want to use disk or washer. Sketch the bounded region R and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're too hung up on "canned methods". You should really try to understand what's going on.

Always, *always* start by sketching the curves.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/erqould4cr

Compute the intersection points and all intercepts with the axis of rotation. Here you have to solve a simple quadratic but you can see that the parabola and the line intersect at $x = 3$ and $x=6$ and only the first intersection is relevant to the problem.

Then, think about the *element of area* that you're rotating about the $x$-axis. In this case, that's a slice of radius $|y|$ and height $dx$, which, when rotated about the $x$-axis, forms an infinitesimal cylinder. Between $x = 2$ and $x=3$, $y$ is given by the parabola, and between $x = 3$ and $x = 4$, $y$ is given by the line. Divide up the problem in that fashion and *sum* the respective volumes you get.

So the volume integral is $\displaystyle V = \pi(\int_2^4(\sqrt{x-2})^2dx + \int_4^6 (\sqrt{x-2})^2 - (x-4)^2 dx)$

Comment: Hi, @Deepak! Thank you for replying. I understand everything you said and you were right that I didn't sketch the curves. However, I was following the graph that was given by my teacher. That graph disregards everything under the x-axis completely, which is why I think that I am not supposed to acknowledge the region under the x-axis between x = 2 and x = 3. So the points that essentially form the region are (2,0), (4,0), and (6,2). I apologize for neglecting to give that info.

Comment: With that in mind and after reading your answer, I believe that the volume integral is essentially the one that you gave except with different limits of integration (2 to 4 for the first integral, 4 to 6 for the second integral). Is this correct? 

My reasoning is that y = x - 4 does not exist at x = 2 (because I'm only considering what is above the x-axis), so having the interval between x = 2 and x = 6 as shown in my original answer does not make sense. 
z

Comment: @Steve I've edited to consider only the area *above* the $x$-axis, please see if you can make sense of it now.

Comment: Yes!!! That is what I figured. Thank you so much for the help. Could you help me with one more? It's essentially the same problem, except that I am now rotating about y = 2. What I did was add a "2 - "(minus) in front of all the functions in parenthesis shown in your volume integral. However, upon evaluation, I am getting 0 for the volume. 
I think I did it correctly with my shell method formula, which produced 56pi/3 as the answer. But I'd like to be able to understand why my integral for the washer didn't work. If you don't want to help any more then I understand! Thanks again.